# What is happening when logcat prints the logs between the time a device was last connected to Android Studio and the present?

Tags: android, debugging, remote-debugging, logcat

Sometimes when a phone connects to Android Studio, it will print logs between the time it was last connected to Android Studio and the present. This is cool, but I can not replicate it. Some times it happens, sometimes it does not.

I have a guess that this is a feature of USB and wireless debugging, and that logs are put in a temporary file so they can be sent to logcat when reconnected. If so, how do I keep the USB debugging from turning off when testing my device in the field during the day, so I can get the logs that were printed during the day? If not, what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The logs are nothing to do with Android Studio (or logcat in general) - it's just system logging happening on the device, and that happens whether it's connected to a log-reader or not.

At a guess, what's happening is your app's process is being closed, so the next time it runs it gets a different *PID* (process ID). When you connect it to the computer, your dropdown shows the *currently running* app process, and filters by its *PID*, so you don't see the old stuff.

You've probably seen this while debugging - if you re-run your app, the log "clears" and gives you a fresh one for the new run of the app. The old log messages are still there (as well as a hell of a lot of other logs for all the stuff going on on the device - it is *noisy*), it's just that you can't see them.

The simple thing to try is going to the filter dropdown on the right of the logcat window, and choose *No filtering*. Then in the filter query thing next to it (with the ) type the name of your app, maybe its package. It's not perfect but it should show you all of the logs it has from your app, along with a bunch of system stuff that's also referring to it. You could get clever with PIDs or setting up a custom filter in the dropdown to get better results.

You might also be interested in [the guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#filtering) (with some filtering tips) and [the commandline version](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) if that's more useful to you